# Asking when a restaurant has available seats

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was calling a restaurant to check if it has available seats at this moment and then found out that it was already full. Then I was trying to ask when the next seat for two was going to be available or how soon can it be available. I was struggling to ask that and wondering what are some grammatical and colloquial way to ask such a thing

Comment: I would ask it as "what's the next available reservation for two?"

Comment: Ask about a _table for two_, not a _seat_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

"How long is the wait for a table for two?"

"What is your next available reservation for two?"

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I wonder if this works as well "How long is the wait time for ..."?

Comment: "How long is the wait (time) for a party of two?" is also perfectly natural.